# Splice on resize function with breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit of JS/jQuery set up on a row of divs. It wraps every three elements in a div `.each-row`.

```
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="each-row">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="each-row">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

The JS code I am using for this is:

```
// Get all the .bricks
var brick = $('.container .brick');
// Loop through all the .bricks
for (var i = 0; i < brick.length; i += 3) {
    // Create container
    var brickContainer = $('<div />', {
        class: 'each-row'
    });
    // Wrap all the .bricks inside the container
    brick.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll(brickContainer);
}
```

Works pretty successfully, but I am wanting to add a few breakpoints in here, so if the screen size is 767px or less, it wraps every `.brick` in `each-row`. If the screen size is less than 1224px is wraps every two, and otherwise wraps every three.

I have this working, using the resize function, and have set up a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2YKZ/3/embedded/result/) but the only issue is that, because of the resize, it's injecting the `each-row` on every pixel iteration. If you look at the DOM when you resize the jsfiddle, you'll see it's adding `each-row` all the time.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to unwrap the elements before wraping them again.

```
function overviewGridResize() {

    $('.each-row').each(function(ind, row){
        $(row) // select the row
            .children()  // take its children
            .detach()  // detach them from row
            .appendTo($(row).parent()); // append them to row's parent
        $(row).remove(); // remove the empty row
    });
    // rest of your code
});
```

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b2YKZ/4/

Comment: The `.detach()` is not needed here.

Comment: Makes perfect sense :) Thanks!